# Teradata REGEXP to find all non-alpha characters

Tags: sql, regex, teradata, non-alphanumeric

The HISTORY_MEMBERS table has undesireable entries in the some of the columns.  The majority are in the Last_Name column.  Some entries were made for testing (TestLastName, test, tester, etc.) and others have non-alpha characters (!, ., /, 9, etc.) I'm tasked with determining how many there are so we can determine what to do about them, if anything.  I'm a fairly new to the field and brand new to Teradata and my usual REGEXP is not functioning in this environment.  Can someone help?

```
SELECT * FROM HISTORY_MEMBER
WHERE Last_Name REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]+$' OR
Last_Name LIKE 'test%' or
LENGTH(Last_Name) <2;
```

I've tried removing the carat and using NOT, no difference.  I'm getting 3707 and when I try to resolve that I get 3706.

Comment: you want https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-VantageTM-SQL-Functions-Expressions-and-Predicates/March-2019/Regular-Expression-Functions/REGEXP_SIMILAR

Comment: Thank you.  Can you elaborate?  I'm unsure how this would work.

Comment: To find a column containing non-alpha characters I would use `where regexp_instr(<you column>,'[^A-Za-z]',1) > 0`

Comment: Or `REGEXP_SIMILAR(Last_Name,'[A-Za-z]+')=1` would be the direct equivalent (effectively, a leading ^ and trailing $ are assumed for REGEXP_SIMILAR).